Sense of parking names at GCTS
What is the reason behind the stand names in GCTS parking/docking chart? I can't find any. There are lots of airports with strange patterns but this one is plainly chaotic evil.
https://aip.enaire.es/AIP/contenido_AIP/AD/AD2/GCTS/LE_AD_2_GCTS_PDC_1_en.pdf

The stands on the airport diagram:

The table below the diagram:

From this table, the common characteristics by stand letter:

G: 400Hz AC is available
AG: anchor point available
J: compatible with A333
H: compatible with B763
R: some incompatibility with another stand occupancy
E: Nothing special.


The lesson I need to learn here is to always read further, even when I think I already have read enough. Thanks!

@Arget: That happens to me too, more often than I like.
